# pytest-bdd reuse same method for different steps

Tags: python, bdd, pytest

I want to use same method for @given, @when and @then of same step.
e.g.

```
Scenario: Launch an application         
    Given username and password entered
    And login button pressed
    Then the app launches

Scenario: Launch application again          
    Given user logged out
    And username and password entered
    When login button pressed
    Then the app launches
```

If I do this in the implementation of step:

```
@when('login button pressed')
@given('login button pressed')
def loginButtonPressed():
    print 'button pressed'
```

It seems, pytest_bdd cannot handle this. I get the error:

> fixture 'login button pressed' not found 
>   Is there a way I can maybe alias the steps?

Comment: Remove one definition, for example when and try to use it with any if them, it should work. Given,When,Then should not influence the step regex.

Comment: Yes, also the function name should be different.

Answer (score 5):

In pytest-BDD it does not currently support the ability to use two different step types/definitions on one function definition. How ever there are "work arounds"

**Option 1: Turn off Gherkin strict mode**

```
@pytest.fixture
def pytestbdd_strict_gherkin():
    return False
```

This will allow you to use steps in any order:

```
@when('login button pressed')
def loginButtonPressed():
    print 'button pressed'
```

In gherkin

```
Scenario: Use given anywhere         
         Given username and password entered
         when login button pressed
         then I am logged in
         when login button pressed
```

*pros:* don't have to create given/when/then versions...

*cons:* can make less readable... goes against true step procedure.

see for more info [Relax strict gherkin](http://pytest-bdd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#relax-strict-gherkin-language-validation)

**Option 2: Call previously defined function in new step definition**

```
@given('login button pressed')
    def loginButtonPressed():
        # do stuff...
        # do more stuff...
        print 'button pressed'

@when('login button pressed')
    def when_loginButtonPressed():
        loginButtonPressed() 

@then('login button pressed')
    def then_loginButtonPressed():
        loginButtonPressed()
```

*pros:* Doesn't duplicate function body code, keep given->when->then pattern. Still maintainable (change code 1 place)

*cons:* Still have to create new function definitions for given, when, then versions...

Comment: Thanks you for the answer. But now I am trying to achieve similar behavior using regex string. That is, I want to pass parameter string from Gherkin. <br/>
<code>
Scenario: Go Somewhere
    Given Go to "<Place1>"
    Then verify went there
    Given Go to "<Place2>"
    Then verify went there
<br/>

@given(parsers.re(r'Go to "(?P<place>.+)" from here'))
def go_there(place):
    print "Went there"
</code>
pytest-bdd gives error:<br/>

GivenAlreadyUsed: Fixture "go_there" that implements this "Go to "<Place2>" " given step has been already used.

Comment: Yes, given steps actually can't be repeated. But whens and then can. So you can make it a when but still use it like a given if your turn of gherkin strict mode

Comment: Ok, great. Thanks.

Comment: I did but my score is less. :(